Cannot invoke "...[Name]Repository" because "this.[name]Repository" is null
I am trying to automatise tests using Cucumber for my Spring Boot Web App, I want to ensure my database is not empty for a test scenario.
The issue is that My repository seem null and I cannot figure out why.
// Definitions: database.java
@Given("Database is not empty")
public void databaseIsNotEmpty()
{
    AccountService service = new AccountService();
    Assert.assertTrue(service.getAccountsCount() != 0);;
}


// Repository: AccountRepository.java
@Repository
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<AccountEntity, Long>
{
    @Query("SELECT p FROM AccountEntity p WHERE p.id = :id")
    AccountEntity getAccountById(@Param("id") Long id);

}

// Service: AccountService.java
@Service
public class AccountService {

    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository accountRepository;

    public List<AccountEntity> getAllAccounts() {
        return accountRepository.findAll();
    }

    public AccountEntity getAccountById(Long id) {
        return accountRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }

    public Long getAccountsCount() { return accountRepository.count(); }
}

Error:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.app.helloworld.repository.AccountRepository.count()" because "this.accountRepository" is null
I could not find any informations on internet, trying random things will probably not help me understanding my mistake.
I found this link but I believe he encounters a slightly different issue since the error only appear during my Cucumber tets and not on runtimes.
A friend of mine told me to try and add
@Autowired
private AccountRepository accountRepository;

But it gave me the error Autowired members must be defined in valid Spring bean (@Component|@Service|...)

This question is similar to: Null Pointer Exception when Calling repository in a class implementing Runnable. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You're creating a new instance with new AccountService();. So ofcourse the fields are null. Spring didn't autowire anything because Spring is not involved. You should autowire the accounts service, not the repository, into your step definitions.
